# Create a list of adjacencies by adjacency matrix

Tags: prolog

I need to write a program that will create a list of adjacencies based on the representation of the graph, given in the form of an adjacency matrix.

Examples

input - a list with lists of elements

```
[[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0]].
```

output

```
[[0,2,3],[1,0,3],[1,2,0]]
```

I've tried this one:

```
indexof(Index, Item, List):-
  nth1(Index, List, Item).

replace(I, L, E, K) :-
  nth1(I, L, _, R),
  nth1(I, K, E, R).

f([], []).
f([H|Tail], [Z|RezTail]):-
    member(E,H),
    E =:= 1,
    indexof(X, E, H),
    replace(X, H, X, Z),
    f(Tail, RezTail).
```

Input - `f([[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0]], Z).`
Output - `Z = [[0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]]`

As you can see the problem is that after finding the first " 1 " the program goes into recursion and skips further items in the list. Is there any option how to avoid this?

Comment: I don't get your input - output example. The third element of the input list is [0,0,1] which means that the third node is adjacent to the third node aka itself?

Comment: @damianodamiano Yeah, sorry, I just pun numbers in the example randomly, I'll fix it. But the whole idea is the same, I need to replace every '1' to it's index in every list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
fh([], [], _).
fh([0|T1], [0|T2], I) :-
  Ip is I+1,
  fh(T1, T2,Ip).
fh([_|T1], [I|T2], I) :-
  Ip is I+1,
  fh(T1, T2, Ip).


f([], []).
f([H1|T1], [H2|T2]) :-
  fh(H1, H2, 1),
  f(T1, T2).
```

so:

```
?- f([[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0]],X).
```

evaluates to:

```
X = [[0, 2, 3], [1, 0, 3], [1, 2, 0]]
```

Comment: Wow, That's great solution. I think I have a problem with functional programming languages coz I get used to objective-oriented languages and trying to use the same methods here.